# Possible To Know When Credentials Are Needed

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I am working with Linked SharePoint tables into Access 2016.  Things work great when SharePoint does not require authentication, which essentially equates to me having to go through the process of re-linking the tables.

When authentication is required Access will just freeze up and turn white, and will lock down the entire computer causing a force reboot to be rquired.  I've left it like so for 30 minutes and never is a message displayed or is any indication as to what is going on.

My question is, How does VBA "receive" the message from SharePoint stating that authentication is required, and I can immediately exit my procedure and inform the user that we need to re-authenticate so the process will work succesfully?